# Log4j / Slf4j Logging to BigQuery

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I use Log4J in a Java project and would like to asynchronously stream my logs to BigQuery. I did some research but couldn't really find a good way to do this. Even though, I think many people do this (I know some that do it for different languages).

Mind you, I found some several years old unmaintained code, but nothing that seems to maintained and that I would consider using in a production project. Also the asynchronous part is very important for me, it should be non-blocking.

Is there a library or some best practices to do this properly?

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://www.fluentd.org/

Comment: @GrahamPolley thanks for hinting me towards fluentd, it looks interesting, but their Java implementation looks a bit weird and doesn't seem to be Log4j or Slf4j compatible. For some reason they also require you to install a client locally on your machine in order to work. Both are reasons for me not to use it, but thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use the Java client library for [Stackdriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries). You can then [export](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/) your logs to [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs#bigquery_name).

Comment: Stackdriver Logging: "For applications running on Google Cloud Platform and Amazon Web Services.". I am neither hosted on GCP nor AWS, but thanks for the links :).

Comment: I am not entirely certain why this is put in this way in the product overview. You can go for example in the Stackdriver Logging [Client Libraries page](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) and run the example code from any place. This will work just fine from your local machine, you don't need to be on a Google Cloud Platform VM or running in an App Engine application.

Comment: It's a bit weird, for AWS: `Note: To use the Logging agent with Amazon EC2 VM instances, you must link your AWS account to a Stackdriver account with Premium Tier service. For more information, see Stackdriver Pricing.`. Are you sure this works from any server? (Source: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation)